# How to delete an attachment in ServiceNow using rest api

Tags: ruby, api, servicenow

I created an attachment in a table in ServiceNow through ecc_queue table using SERVICENOW REST api. For creating an attachment I added an entry in ecc_queue table and attachment was created in the corresponding table. Now, I want to delete that attachment I tried by deleting the entry in the ecc_queue table but still the attachment is showing up. Can you please tell me how to delete the attachment. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the corresponding entry in SysAttachment table did the trick.